# Facebook graph API. How to check if post is commentable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing web application which connects to Facebook. And I have two problems, which I hope somebody can help to solve.

1) I have a web application which retrieves posts from users page.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/posts
```

I want to make a possibility to comment the posts from my web application. But it is not allowed to comment some posts. I am getting back

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story","code":100,"type":"OAuthException"}}
```

So I want to disable commenting for some of posts. For example, one of returned posts:

```
{
  "id": "100007531813062_1397508730510174", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Ievgen  Antonenko", 
    "id": "100007531813062"
  }, 
  "story": "Ievgen  Antonenko is now using Facebook in English (UK).", 
  "story_tags": {
    "0": [
      {
        "id": "100007531813062", 
        "name": "Ievgen  Antonenko", 
        "offset": 0, 
        "length": 17, 
        "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100007531813062/posts/1397508730510174"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2014-02-14T11:05:48+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2014-02-14T11:05:48+0000"
}
```

It is not possible to comment this post. I was told that I can check if there is an action with "name": "Comment". But it seems to be wrong because example above contains this property. So the question is, how can I check if post is allowed to be commented?

2) I create a post of type "photo". Than I am trying to post a comment from my web application

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments?method=post&message=msg&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It posts the comment but returns

```
"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","code":2,"type":"OAuthException"
```

instead of comment id.  For other posts it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Facebook, I wonder how to disable comment feature when I post a status.